# Reusable component React - string as a prop

Tags: reactjs

These are all the same component but with one word changed. How to turn it into 1 reusable component?

```
const TabRoles: React.FC<{}> = () => (
  <Box>
    <h1>Roles coming soon!</h1>
  </Box>
)

const TabTraining: React.FC<{}> = () => (
  <Box>
    <h1>Training coming soon!</h1>
  </Box>
)

const TabHours: React.FC<{}> = () => (
  <Box>
    <h1>Hours coming soon!</h1>
  </Box>
```

This is how I am currently calling the consts:

```
<TabRoles key={'volunteer_roles_tab'} />,
<TabHours key={'volunteer_hours_tab'} />,
<TabTraining key={'volunteer_training_tab'} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
const TabTitle: React.FC<{title: string}> = ({ title }) => (
  <Box>
    <h1>{title} coming soon!</h1>
  </Box>
)

<TabTitle key="volunteer_roles_tab" title="Roles" />
<TabTitle key="volunteer_training_tab" title="Training" />
<TabTitle key="volunteer_hours_tab" title="Hours" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add props in React.js:

```
const Tab: React.FC<{subject:string}> = ({subject}) => (
  <Box>
    <h1>${subject} coming soon!</h1>
  </Box>
)

<Tab subject="Roles" />
<Tab subject="Training" />
<Tab subject="Hours" />
```

PS.: You don't need to use `key`s unless you're creating lists of elements.